# check if list is null in c# method

Tags: c#, xml

hello to all  i have this method

```
    public void insertXmlNode(string XmlParentNodeName, List<string> XmlNodeName, List<string> XmlNodeValue, List<string> XmlAttributeName, List<string> XmlAttributeValue)
    {

        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(_connection);
        XmlNode xparent = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//" + XmlParentNodeName);
        if (xparent == null)
        {
            xparent = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, XmlParentNodeName, null);
            xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xparent);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= XmlNodeName.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode xnode = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, XmlNodeName[i], null);
            xnode.InnerText = XmlNodeValue[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlAttributeName.ToString()))
            {
                XmlAttribute xattribute = xdoc.CreateAttribute(XmlAttributeName[i]);
                xattribute.Value = XmlAttributeValue[i];
                xnode.Attributes.Append(xattribute);
            }
            xparent.AppendChild(xnode);
        }

        xdoc.Save(_connection);
    }
```

and i call this like below:

```
_db.insertXmlNode("Orders", _orderName, _orderValue, null, null);
```

> "_db is a class instanc and _orderName & _orderValue has list string "

i wanna if XmlAttributeName not null add attribute to xml node but i
get this error

> value can't be null

how i can check if XmlAttributeName not null do somthing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the check this way, as you said in comment :

```
if (XmlAttributeName != null || 
    XmlAttributeName.All(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
{
    .......
}
```

Try to do it this way :

```
if (XmlAttributeName != null && 
    XmlAttributeName.All(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
{
    .......
}
```

With `&&` operator 2nd condition will only be checked if the 1st condition met. And code execution will enter `if` block, only if `XmlAttribute`is not null and all attributes in the list is not null or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool HasInvalidValues(IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable == null || enumerable.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to check for nullity is `if(XmlAttributeName != null)`. This kind of check is ubiquitous for reference types; even `Nullable<T>` overrides the equality operator to be a more convenient way of expressing `nullable.HasValue` when checking for nullity.

If you do `if(!XmlAttributeName.Equals(null))` then you will get a `NullReferenceException` if `data == null`. Which is kind of comical since avoiding this exception was the goal in the first place.

```
if (XmlAttributeName != null && 
XmlAttributeName.All(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
{
   // do here
}
```